# If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, then $\text{D}f$ will be an $m\times n$ matrix giving a linear function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> In general, if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is any function then $\text{D}f$ will be an $m\times n$ matrix and so gives a linear function from $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$.

Can someone please explain this concept and give examples? I do not understand what it is saying.

This is in the context of the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: F needs to be (Frechet) differentiable. Apriori, the derivative of F may not exist.

Comment: @DanielLautzenheiser I don't think that's what I'm asking. The question is clear, in my opinion.

Comment: Anyone? Is there a problem with the way I'm asking the question?

Comment: It would be better if you format your post with MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I edited it as much as I could. I'm unsure how to make the arrows work and there's also a word limit. I'd appreciate it if someone could clean this up for me.

Comment: To clarify, what is 'DF'?

Comment: @StubbornAtom The partial derivative of the function.

Comment: The derivative of a vector function of one variable is a column vector. The derivative of a scalar function of multiple variables is a row vector. The derivative of a vector function of multiple variables combines the two ideas together.

Comment: @ThePointer: There's a word limit, because it's encouraging you to ask your question in your question, not in your title.

Comment: @Hurkyl Acknowledge. My apologies.

Comment: @ThePointer It is not a partial derivative, it is the _total_ derivative (i.e., it describes variations in all directions at once), and that is why it is described by a matrix rather than by a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $Df$ is not a matrix.

Suppose $f$ is defined over an open set $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and Fréchet-differentiable at $a\in A$. Then, *by definition*, $Df(a)$ is a linear map
$$
Df(a)\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m
$$
such that
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\|f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)(h)\|}{\|h\|}=0
$$
If $f$ is Fréchet-differentiable at all points of $A$ and $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ is the vector space of linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, we get a map
$$
Df\colon A\to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)
$$
(which is obviously not a matrix). However, $Df(a)$, as a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ *can* be identified with the associated $m\times n$ matrix with respect to the standard basis; if we do this identification, then $Df(a)(h)$ is just the matrix product when we consider $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as a column vector.

However, I recommend not to think in terms of matrices, but in more abstract terms; matrices are very good for doing computations.

Consider the map $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$
f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}\right)=
\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2+x_2^2 \\ x_1x_2\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, for $a=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, $Df(a)$ exists and is the linear map represented (with respect to the standard basis) by the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2a_1 & 2a_2 \\
a_2 & a_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where you can recognize the Jacobian matrix at the point.

In other words, $Df$ is a map that associates, to each point where $f$ is differentiable, a linear map that *can* be identified with a matrix, provided we have a canonical identification to begin with (it is only possible on spaces of the form $\mathbb{R}^n$).

However, the power of this definition is that it applies to functions defined on *arbitrary* normed vector spaces; you can for instance consider
$$
f\colon M_n(\mathbb{R})\to M_n(\mathbb{R^n}),
\qquad
f(A)=A^TA
$$
where $M_n(\mathbb{R^n})$ is the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices. There is no canonical way to associate a matrix to $Df(A)$, but the function is still differentiable at any point (you may enjoy computing the derivative).

Comment: Saying an element of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ is not an $m \times n$ matrix is very close in spirit to saying that an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a $n \times 1$ matrix.

Comment: @Hurkyl Where did I say that an element of $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ is not a matrix? I said that the *map* $Df\colon A\to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ is not a matrix, which you'll agree is quite different. Indeed, I say that $Df(a)$ *can* be identified with a matrix. I think that the distinction between $Df$ and $Df(a)$ is very important.

Comment: It didn't even cross my mind that you would want to distinguish between matrices whose entries are scalar-valued functions and functions whose values are matrices of scalars. I'm not sure that distinction is particularly important. (I would agree on paying attention to the typing of $Df$ and $Df(a)$, though)

Comment: @Hurkyl Are you a physicist? `;-)` However, even if we identify $Df$ with a matrix having scalar valued functions as entries, it doesn't define a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$, but *a family of linear maps*. Only $Df(a)$ is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @Hurkyl And the distinction becomes important when going up to Fréchet derivatives on Banach spaces, where matrices play no role.

Comment: Nope, mathematician who has had occasion to do enough (multi)linear algebra to really value the fact that matrix algebra eliminates a lot of the juggling between things that are essentially the same. To the point that I prefer notation inspired by it even in the abstract; e.g. if $T$ is a linear operator on $V$, its corresponding action on $V^*$ I will write as $\omega T$, rather than something like $T^*(\omega)$.

Comment: I'm not sure the distinction is relevant in the abstract either; there's the natural embedding $\mathcal{L}(V,W)^A \hookrightarrow \mathcal{L}(V^A, W^A)$ (where $X^A$ is the space of functions from the set $A$ to the space $X$)

Comment: @Hurkyl And I have done enough abstract algebra to know the distinction is important; $T^*(\omega)=\omega T$, that's true, but you're still confusing a *map* with its action on a particular element.

Comment: This doesn't address my question, though. Come on guys. I'm not sure why people insist posting complex mathematical responses and then arguing over it, when it does nothing to address the OP. This isn't a difficult question, either. This is first year college math.

Comment: @ThePointer Why are you saying my answer doesn't address your question? $Df$ is a map with a certain domain (not a vector space, in general) and a certain codomain. If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $Df(a)$ is a linear map, which you can, if you prefer, identify with a matrix.

Comment: Ok. There was a lot of asides in your original answer that did not directly answer what I was asking. Care to show an explained example? Such abstract explanations are generally useless for learning.

Comment: @ThePointer I added a couple of examples that should explain my preference for not considering $Df(a)$ as a matrix in general (though it can in special cases).

Comment: @egreg Got it. Thank you for your answer and help. I greatly appreciate it. :)